# Can't change a navigation bar color

Tags: android, android-styles

I am trying to draw a white navigation bar with black button on splash (`Theme.Paper.Launcher`) and after change a background color to `@color/primary_dark` (`Theme.Paper`):

**style-v27**:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Basic paper theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Paper" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.Paper.ActionMode</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">false</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Splash theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Paper.Launcher" parent="Theme.Paper">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But my navigation bar is still black with white buttons. What am I doing wrongly?

**P.S.** There is Android Oreo on my phone...